# jlabel and paintComponent in same jframe in java

Tags: java

the code down here only calls the class(class "oefen") whith the code that makes a jframe and a ball(using the painComponent method)and if you press the arrow keys it moves in that direction...it works fine but when i add the target(jlabel) to the jframe only the target shows and nothing else..please help me to put the target and ball in the same frame

```
public class theFrame implements KeyListener {

    public  static JFrame j = new JFrame();
    public static ImageIcon tar = new ImageIcon("c://fruit//target.png");
    public static JLabel target = new JLabel(tar);
    public static JPanel p = new JPanel();
    public static void main(String args[]){
        j.setSize(500,600);
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setVisible(true);
        oefen o = new oefen();
        j.add(o);
        target.setLayout(null);
        target.setSize(100,100);
        target.setLocation(250,0);
        j.add(target);
    }

}
```

thanks

public class theFrame extends JComponent {

```
public  static JFrame j = new JFrame();
public static ImageIcon tar = new ImageIcon("c://fruit//target.png");
public static JLabel target = new JLabel(tar);
public static JPanel p = new JPanel();
public static oefen o = new oefen();
public static void main(String args[]){

    j.setSize(500,600);
    j.setLayout(null);
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setVisible(true);
    target.setLayout(null);
    target.setSize(0,0);
    target.setLocation(0,0);
    j.add(o);
    j.add(target);
}
```

}

if i set the JFrame Layout to null notihng shows...the code above shows how i set the JFrameLayout cuz i don't know if its wrong.
please help

Answer (score 0):

try setting the JFrames layout to null too, because you use absolute positioning.

Comment: if i set the jframeLayout to null nothing shows,please help.